# Update function returns non-updated records

Tags: postgresql, function

I have the PostgreSQL function below to update a set of records and I want it to return the same list of records after being updated. Right now it's returning the list of records before they are update (`flag_read=FALSE` in the returned set). I know the update works well because when I query the table after executing the function I can see `flag_read=TRUE`.

How could I change the function to return the updated set of records?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION base.mark_all_notifications_as_read()
RETURNS SETOF base.notification AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    WITH unread_notifications AS (
      UPDATE base.notification
      SET flag_read=TRUE 
      WHERE flag_read=FALSE
      AND created_by_id=base.get_current_user_id()
      RETURNING id
    )
    SELECT * FROM base.notification a
    WHERE a.id IN (SELECT id FROM unread_notifications);
END;
$$ language plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a simple `UPDATE..RETURNING *`.  The needless WITH and the SELECT are what causes the problem.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html:

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other
>   and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying
>   statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually
>   happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same
>   snapshot (see Chapter 13), so they cannot “see” one another's effects
>   on the target tables. This alleviates the effects of the
>   unpredictability of the actual order of row updates, and means that
>   RETURNING data is the only way to communicate changes between
>   different WITH sub-statements and the main query.

**EDIT:** Adding the complete function as example

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION base.mark_all_notifications_as_read()
RETURNS SETOF base.notification AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    UPDATE base.notification
    SET flag_read=TRUE 
    WHERE flag_read=FALSE
    AND created_by_id=base.get_current_user_id()
    RETURNING *;
END;
$$ language plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Comment: @alexis.rolland You don't actually need PL/pgSQL for this either. A simple `languag sql` function will work just as well